# HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required Error - Twitter API

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, twitter-streaming-api

Getting Error 401 while sending the below request for stream api .
however when i just try using curl with authorization header it works properly .
Please advice what m doing wrong.

```
REQUEST
GET /1.1/statuses/filter.json HTTP/1.1
Accept: /
User-Agent: Qapla
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?language=en&oauth_consumer_key=GuYuxjwY&oauth_nonce=u4a3R_n&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=153693&oauth_token=103405936-vfmrGkclVE8siUIF&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=R2qVlT2aLVgi8SMA%3D
Host: stream.twitter.com

ERROR RESPONSE
HTTP/1.1
401
Authorization
Required
cache-control:
must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
connection:
close
content-length:
266
content-type:
text/html
date:
Fri,
14
Sep
2018
15:19:31
GMT
server:
tsa
www-authenticate:
Basic
realm=“Firehose”
x-connection-hash:
cd3e38a2d55e0a8831776b96d862d3a2
```

Answer (score 1):

The authorization header is invalid , it should not be a url , rather it should be some has kind of value , in case u have access to the API , you will find it in the API console

Comment: Thanks sanjay . Do you mean something like this Authorization:
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog",
oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1318622958",
oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb",

Comment: Thanks Sanjay . I modified the Request Message . It worked.